# copy /a, copy /b - use of this options

Tags: windows-server-2008, cmd.exe

On Microsof Windows Server 2008 (R1), 32-Bit, I have some trouble understanding the **use of** as well as the **difference between**

`copy /a` and `copy /b`

The [Technet Article on `copy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx) doesn't help me much:

> `copy /a` → … copy an ASCII text file that uses an end-of-file character (that is, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) to indicate the end of the file. … The effect of `/a` depends on its position in the command-line string. When `/a` follows Source, *`copy` treats the file as an ASCII file and copies data that precedes the first end-of-file character*.
>   `copy /b` directs the command interpreter to read the number of bytes specified by the file size in the directory. `/b` is the default value for copy, unless copy combines files. … The effect of `/b` depends on its position in the commandline string. When `/b` follows Source, *`copy` copies the entire file, including any end-of-file character*.
>   [→ source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490886.aspx)

This is quite confusing for me[,](https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/6389733888/h30741C96/) as I thought that `copy` simply clones a file to another destination.

Question: An actual example where `copy /a` and⁄or `copy /b` would make a difference would help me greatly in understanding the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply avoid COPY/A

What I would expect it to do is to copy information up to the first EOF (Ctrl-Z) character, and then truncate the file after that.  So if you had a file that said "HELLO^M^ZGREETINGS", then the result would simply say "HELLO^M".

It might also do some interesting stuff with Unix text files, like convert them to MS-DOS ASCII format.  Such things were considered beneficial in the early days of DOS when people were more prone to translate text files to the native format of their own operating system.  This was probably viewed as a feature that really helped to enhance compatibility.

These could be highly desirable things, in theory.  But probably not in most cases.  In most cases, you want an exact copy of the bits of the original file.  So Copy/B is desired.  Copy/B is also generally the default.  (It is the default for files; it might not be the default if you don't specify a file as the source.)

For instance, with at least some version of DOS I have used Copy/B as follows:

Copy/B config1.txt+config2.txt config3.txt

I believe that without the /B, specifying multiple filenames could result in the source being treated as a non-binary source.  However, I seem to recall figuring out later that the precise behavior could vary based on what command shell I'm using.  That could mean different versions of the operating system, or perhaps using a shell like JP Software's 4DOS, which I have been known to use on regularly.

Same sort of thing, by the way, as FTP's ability to transfer files in ASCII mode or binary mode.  Perhaps useful in theory, but probably actually causes more confusion than help.  That's even more true with CMD's COPY/A than FTP.

Answer (score 1):

No. Copy is a writer executable function. I think is is an herederity behavior from MS-DOS. For example, you could write your own file without using any editor as EDIT. For eg, to create a file:

```
copy:con myfile.txt
Hello world!
This is other line
^Z
```

In the above example, ^Z is the sign for "CONTROL+Z" that means: "END OF FILE".

Now, for your question, When you use the first statement, you mean something like that. You are in "ASCII" copying-append mode. The second version is a "BINARY" version, well knowdledge by everyone.

If my answer seems to be a little dark, please comment and I'll be glad to update it :)